# any way to find & change which Log Analytics workspace being used by Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Trying to find any way to change Log Analytics workspace being used by Application Insights. As of now, all the data being written to the default workspace from all the subscriptions(have more than 1 subscription). Planning to create one workspace per subscription and direct the data from the correspondingly.

AD

Comment: You cannot change it right now. This functionality is coming.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Wow. Looks like this functionality is already there!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the [workspace-based Application Insights resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource#modifying-the-associated-workspace) which is in preview currently, you can modify the associated workspace from within the Application Insights resource pane, select Properties > Change Workspace > Log Analytics Workspace. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource#modifying-the-associated-workspace) document for additional details.

[image]

However if you are using the Application Insights Connector Management Solution to view the Application Insights application telemetry in Log Analytics, would like to call out that the connector has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-connector). Please refer to [the process documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-connector#removing-the-connector-with-powershell) to remove the connector with PowerShell. Using [cross-resource query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query#using-cross-resource-query-for-multiple-resources) you can directly query Application Insights data from Log Analytics.

Hope the above information helps, please revert back if you have any other queries. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helps :)

Comment: Glad to hear Diwakar that the response helped, please accept the answer or upvote so that other community members can also find this answer if they have similar query. Thank you